# PowerShell ForEach statement failing

Tags: powershell, foreach

I am having an issue with a ForEach statement which I am sure it super simple to fix but so far no luck.

The ForEach runs great against each item, but stops when an error is encountered. I need it to just continue. Does anyone have any ideas? I have added 'Continue' but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Thanks!

```
$objects | ForEach-Object -Process {
    try { 
$ErrorActionPreference = "Continue"          
$extensionproperty_all = Get-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectID $_.UserPrincipalName
$extensionproperty_workemail = $extensionproperty_all.get_item("extension_appID_WorkDay_WorkEmail")
Set-AzureADUser -objectid $_.UserPrincipalName -OtherMails $extensionproperty_workemail
Write-output "email updated for $extensionproperty_workemail"}
    catch {
    Write-Warning "Error encountered with 1 or more entries"
    Continue}
}
```

Comment: Change to `$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'` and put that line **above** the ForEach-Object loop. Using that, also non-terminating exceptions make the code enter the `catch{..}` block where you can deal with it or ignore it. Inside the catch{..} block, remove the `Continue` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the error to trap therefore use `-ErrorAction Stop`

```
$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'
$objects | ForEach-Object -Process {
    Try { 
        $extensionproperty_all = Get-AzureADUserExtension -ObjectID $_.UserPrincipalName
        $extensionproperty_workemail = $extensionproperty_all.get_item("extension_appID_WorkDay_WorkEmail")
        Set-AzureADUser -objectid $_.UserPrincipalName -OtherMails $extensionproperty_workemail
        Write-output "email updated for $extensionproperty_workemail"}
    Catch {
    # Because -ErrorAction preference is Stop, any errors will process from here
        Write-Warning "Error encountered with 1 or more entries:"
    # You could use the default variable $_ - within the Catch block this contains the error.
    }
}
```

There are better way to structure your code here, but this should work.

Comment: This did it. Thank you so much.